# C++, multimap, дублирование ключей

Tags: c++, map

Подскажите, происходит ли реальное дублирование ключей при вставке значений с одинаковым ключом в `std::multimap`?

Comment: да. Иначе вы не смогли бы хранить разные значения в одних и тех же ключах

Comment: Теоретически, конечно, можно исключить дублирование ключа, но тогда будет путаница с тем, когда ключ удалять, а когда нет, и как. Понял, спасибо.

Comment: никто не мешает сделать мултимап на базе обычного мапа, только значения будут вектором (списком).

Comment: если вам ненужно, чтобы ключи дублировались, то для этого есть `map`

Comment: Да это-то понятно, мне просто стало интересно, есть ли по умолчанию такая оптимизация в multimap, и если есть, то какая магия решает вопрос с уничтожением дублирующихся ключей)

Comment: Мне нужно хранить разные объекты под общим ключом, причем реализовывать это на C, вот я и интересуюсь, что происходит внутри std::multimap, методом тыка это проверять долго, а смотреть в stl файлы просто страшно, там сам черт ногу сломит.

Comment: Мультимап, как и обычный мап, позволяет итерировать по парам. Реализовывать это каким-либо иным способом, кроме явного хранения пар - никому не нужное извращение.

Comment: там страшно, потому что там красно-черное дерево. А без теоретической подготовки оно действительно страшно.https://habr.com/post/66926/

Comment: Да я знаю, как работает красно-черное дерево, смотреть на stl страшно из-за вида идентификаторов, которые, такое ощущение, что генерировались автоматизированным алгоритмом, а не человеком.

Comment: А идентификаторы в стандартной библиотеке используются из соображений непересечения с идентификаторами (с макросами прежде всего) из пользовательского кода.

Answer (score 1):

А, простите, какая разница? Если ключи одинаковы? :)
Шутка, если непонятно...

А вообще - обратите внимание, что отображения работают с **парами**, и даже стандартный аллокатор описан как

```
class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
```

Так что происходит скорее не дублирование, а хранение ключа вместе со значением.

Ключ тоже может быть составным - и тогда если использовать один ключ на все значения, можно его по сути потерять.

Ну, а вот простенькая [тестовая программка](https://ideone.com/Hw6tBo):

```
struct Key
{
    int value, id;
};

bool operator <(const Key& a, const Key& b)
{
    return a.value < b.value;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    multimap<Key,int> m;
    m.insert(make_pair(Key{1,1},11));
    m.insert(make_pair(Key{1,2},12));
    m.insert(make_pair(Key{1,3},13));
    m.insert(make_pair(Key{2,1},21));
    m.insert(make_pair(Key{2,2},22));
    m.insert(make_pair(Key{2,3},23));

    for(auto x: m)
        cout << x.first.value << ":" << x.first.id
            << "   " << x.second << endl;
}
```

Убедитесь, что все ключи - при их одинаковости для `multimap` - таки разные...

Answer (score 1):

Происходящее можно грубо преставить так:

```
template < class Key, class T >
class My_multimap {
    using Tp = std::pair< Key, std::list<T> >;
    std::set<Tp> s;
    using iterator = typename set<Tp>::iterator;
    //...
public:
    // тут operator[](const Key& key) должен выдать список значений, что неудобно
    // для использования и при работе с экземплярами класса придется
    // задействовать другой обьект(для моего случая  std::list<T>)
    // поэтому определяются функции возвращения итераторов на начало и конец списка
    iterator // итератор на начало списка
    lower_bound(const Key&) const;
    iterator // итератор на место за конец списка
    upper_bound(const Key&) const;
    std::pair<iterator, iterator> // пара (начало, конец)
    equal_range(const Key&) const;
    //...
};
```

Таким образом ключ отображает целый список значений, а доступ к ним осуществляется итераторами на этот список, в отличии от простого map, который просто выдает уникальное значение